# How do I make a HttpRequest to an apex webservice expecting a RestRequest object?

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, httprequest

Here's my code:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();

req.setEndpoint(Constants.SF_BASE_URL + '/services/apexrest/peer/v1/loanAccounts/setupOneTimeACH/' + (String)contract.get('Id'));
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

Map<String, String> urlParams = new Map<String, String>();

String payload = ' { ' +
                 '   "bankId" : "' +  (String)bankAccount.get('Id') + '", ' +
                 '   "paymentAmount" : ' + txnAmount + ', ';
if(feeAmount != null) {
    payload += '   "feeAmount" : ' + feeAmount + ', '; 
}

payload += '   "debitDate" : "' +  String.valueOf(datetimeToDate(txnDebitDate)) + '", ' +
           '   "accountId" : "' +  (String)customerDetail.get('Id') + '"' +
           ' } ';

System.debug(payload);
req.setBody(payload);
System.debug(req);
res = http.send(req);
```

And here's the webservice code, well, at least the important parts:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/loanAccounts/setupOneTimeACH/*')
global class SetupOneTimeACH {
    @HttpPost
    global static Response setupOneTimeACH() {
        RestRequest restReq = RestContext.request;       
        RestResponse restRes = RestContext.response;
        Response res = new Response();

        UrlParser parser = UrlParser.parseUrl(restReq.requestURI, '/v1/loanAccounts/setupOneTimeACH');
        String paramId = (parser != null ? parser.id : null);
        if(paramId == null || paramId.trim() == '') {
            res.status = Constants.ERROR;
            res.errorCode = Constants.INVALID_INPUT;
            res.errorMessage = System.Label.LOAN_ACCOUNT_ID_NULL;
            restRes.statuscode = Constants.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
            return res;
        }

        Map<String, Object> reqParams = getJsonParamsFromRequest(restReq);
        if(reqParams == null) {
            res.status = Constants.ERROR;
            res.errorCode = Constants.INVALID_INPUT;
            res.errorMessage = System.Label.UNABLE_PARSE_REQ_PARAMS;
            restRes.statuscode = Constants.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
            return res;
        }   
    ....
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> getJsonParamsFromRequest(RestRequest req) {
        if(req != null && req.requestBody != null && (req.requestBody.toString().trim().length() != 0)) {
            try {
                return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString()));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug('Exception : ' + e);
                //return null;
                throw e;      // Raise the exception for invalid JSON
            }
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

By the way, the error I get is `System.Label.UNABLE_PARSE_REQ_PARAMS`.

For sundry reasons, a HttpRequest is the only way I can call the webservice. However, the webservice requires a RestRequest object with a json payload. So when I try making the call, it throws me an error saying I haven't specified any parameters.

I've tried looking around and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Could you post your @RestResource Apex class? Also, look into using Apex's JSON API instead of concatenating a JSON string.

Comment: (a) You should definitely be able to call the method without resorting to a callout, (b) you definitely should be using JSON.serialize instead of constructing raw strings, and (c) it sounds like the code is expecting (for whatever reason) a query string instead of a JSON payload. I don't think we can really help you without at least seeing a bit of the class/method you're calling.